# Why preprocessor doesn't expand type defined later in the code

Tags: c

My question is relatively simple and yet mystery to me.

After peprocessing `BLA_Str` isn't expanded to `bla_Str`. This is the case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef BLA_Str blaInstance;

#define BLA_Str bla_Str

typedef struct 
{
   int bla;
}bla_Str;

void main(void){
//  printf("%u\n\r",5);
}
```

Comment: The preprocessor is not psychic.

Comment: FFS C compilation is slow enough as it is.  Just how many passes through the source code do you want?

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: Have you compiled this code?

Comment: Yes and examined the file after the preprocessor. A saw this `typedef BLA_Str blaInstance;`

Comment: I don't understand the downvote?!?

Comment: I found the code in my head

Comment: @Hairi - I think you need to push the Hoover around more often!

Comment: @ Ed Heal Could guide me in finding the meaning of: "Push the Hoover araund" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor just performs a single pass through the file, expanding macros as it goes, and adding macros to its list when it encounters the `#define`. When it gets to the line

```
typedef BLA_Str blaInstance
```

it doesn't yet know about the `BLA_Str` macro, so it leaves it unchanged in the output.

You shold generally put all the `#define` lines at the beginning, so they'll affect everything in the rest of the file.

You can find a reasonable summary of how the C preprocessor works in [The C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter7/directives.html). It explains:

> There are two ways of defining macros, one of which looks like a function and one which does not. Here is an example of each:
>
> ```
>    #define FMAC(a,b) a here, then b
>    #define NONFMAC some text here
> ```
>
> Both definitions define a macro and some replacement text, which will be used to replace **later** occurrences of the macro name in the rest of the program.

If a macro expands into another macro, this is handled with *rescanning*:

> Once the processing described above has occurred, the replacement text plus the following tokens of the source file is rescanned, looking for more macro names to replace. The one exception is that, within a macro's replacement text, the name of the macro itself is not expanded.

Comment: @Bramar "The preprocessor just performs a single pass through the file"

Is it a rule, or it is the case for my code/file? For example 

`#define digit one` 
`#define one 1`

`int a = digit;`

This code is ok, but if the preprocessor passes the file only once there should be error. This is just my own reasoning.

Comment: It only goes through the file once, but it will repeatedly expand each line until there are no more macros in it. So first it expands `int a = digit` to `int a = one`, then it expands that to `int a = 1`.

Comment: Thanks I very much appreciate your help.